# Changing tor's default listening port withing the torrc file

Tags: configuration

I have downloaded and installed the tor browser bundle.
I would like to run tor as a single process alone without the browser, so I've been launching the tor.exe which exists in `[%Tor Directory%]\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor`, but first I changed tor's config file `torrc` as follow:

```
SocksListenAddress 127.0.0.1:9200
SocksPort 9200
```

but the listening port used by tor has never changed, and tor keeps listening on the same default port which is 9050.
**Note** that "torrc" file is located in `[%Tor Directory%]\Browser\TorBrowser\Data`.

I would like to know why tor is not listening on the configured port? is there any missing step that I should be aware of?

Comment: Where is the original `torrc` and where did you place your changes?

Comment: As i just said, the torrc file exists in the installation folder of tor \Browser\TorBrowser\Data

Comment: As of June 16, 2019 Tor Win Dir https://www.torproject.org/download/tor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `torrc` file should be in `Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor`, not `Browser\TorBrowser\Data`.

Check if the the file is in correct path. Check also that the `torrc-defaults` file which may be overriding the changes in your `torrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you want to run the Tor process from the TBB?
If not, I think a standalone Tor (expert bundle) installation could be better suited for your needs. You can get it [here](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en).