# Tor version 7.0 change default listening port

Tags: configuration

I am using tor version 7.0a3,

To change the tor default listening port from `9150` I change the `torrc-defaults` located in `Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor` like below

```
SocksPort 8080 IPv6Traffic PreferIPv6 KeepAliveIsolateSOCKSAuth
```

But it seems that it is not effected at all. When I open the `torrc` file, I see

```
SocksPort 127.0.0.1:9150 IPv6Traffic PreferIPv6 KeepAliveIsolateSOCKSAuth
```

I see this in log

```
[NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
[NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
[NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
[NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
[NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
[NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
[NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
[NOTICE] Bootstrapped 50%: Loading relay descriptors 
[WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
[WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
[WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
[NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
[NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
[NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
[NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

I have reviewed It also mentioned in [Changing tor's default listening port withing the torrc file](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6283/changing-tors-default-listening-port-withing-the-torrc-file) and it does not work ( maybe it changed in tor version 7 )

Comment: Those logs show Tor failing to bootstrap, it can't connect to the Tor network. It's unrelated to the SOCKS port, and you can define more than one SOCKS port so it being defined twice shouldn't matter.

Comment: about:config->network.proxy.socks_port
set the value to whatever your want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to set [Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) and let Tor Browser handle it for you.

The best way to set these differs between operating systems, but instead of editing the torrc, simply setting. Under Linux simple running `env TOR_SOCKS_PORT=12345 ./start-tor-browser.desktop` would suffice, under Windows you need to set them from the `System` -> `Advanced System Settings` -> `Advanced Tab` -> `Environment Variables`.

`TOR_SOCKS_PORT` to the port value you want it to use should work. Similarly `TOR_CONTROL_PORT` controls what port it uses for the control port.